# Normal subgroup must appear as a term in Jordan-Holder Series

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone help me with this? I have proved the assertion in affirmative.

Let G have a Jordan-Holder composition series $\Sigma$ : G = G$_{0}$ $\gneq$ G$_{1}$ $\gneq$ ... $\gneq$ G$_{n}$ = $\{$e$\}$ then

If N is trivial normal subgroup $\{$e$\}$ or all of G then obviously it appears as a term in $\Sigma$.

If N is non-trivial normal subgroup and if G$_{i}$ $\gneq$ N $\gneq$ G$_{i+1}$ then we have that N/G$_{i+1}$ $\triangleleft$ G$_{i}$/G$_{i+1}$ contradicting the fact that the successive quotients (called i$^{th}$ graded component of $\Sigma$) is always simple in a J-H series.

Answer (score 0):

What assertion do you think you have proved? You proved that a normal subgroup can't appear strictly between two terms in a composition series (which I guess could be called a Jordan-Hölder series, why not). But... so what? Consider the example $G = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ with the following composition series:
$$
  G \geq \langle 3 \rangle \geq \{0\}.
$$
This is a composition series in which the normal subgroup $\langle 2 \rangle$ does not appear as a term. Here is another series for the same group:
$$
  G \geq \langle 2 \rangle \geq \{0\}.
$$
This time the normal subgroup $\langle 3 \rangle$ does not appear.

Let's take a closer look at your idea for a proof. Suppose $G$ is a finite group, $G = G_0 \geq G_1 \geq \dotsb \geq G_n = \{e\}$ is a composition series, and $N \leq G$ is a normal subgroup. There exists an $i$ such that $N \subseteq G_i$; for example $i=0$ works. Let $i_0$ be the largest $i$ such that $N \subseteq G_i$. And also there exists a $j$ such that $G_j \subseteq N$; for example $j = n$ works. Let $j_0$ be the smallest $j$ such that $G_j \subseteq N$. Certainly $j_0 \geq i_0$. And if $j_0 = i_0$ then $N = G_{i_0}$. What if $j_0 > i_0$?

Now if $j_0 = i_0+1$, then your proof idea works. We have $G_{i_0+1} \subseteq N \subseteq G_i$. So either $N = G_{i_0}$, or $N = G_{i_0+1}$, or, as you observed, then there is a contradiction because $N/G_{i_0+1}$ is a normal subgroup of $G_{i_0}/G_{i_0+1}$, the series admits a refinement, and we assumed we're starting with a composition series; it's not supposed to admit any refinements.

But if $j_0 \neq i_0+1$ then there is no contradiction. For example, if $j_0 = i_0+2$, then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G_{i_0} / G_{i_0+2}$. But... that's not a simple group. It has $G_{i_0+1}/G_{i_0+2}$ as a nontrivial proper normal subgroup, and it could perhaps have other nontrivial proper normal subgroups. And $N/G_{i_0+2}$ could be one of those.

Since I wrote all this, I will leave it for you to work out the $i_0$ and $j_0$ for each of the two examples listed above in $G = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.